# what is difference between ngClass and clas binding?

Tags: angular

what is difference between ngClass and clas binding?

Both accepts same syntax. Only difference I saw was class can do this: `[class.sale]="onSale"`.

Both accepts almost similar syntax:

```
[ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp"
```

```
[class]="string | Record<string, boolean | undefined | null> | Array<string>"
```

I've read some answers on SO. But they are few years ago. I think now the angular team had made both expression similar.

Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Use `[ngClass]` for conditionally applying **multiple** classes and use `[class.sale]` for conditionally applying a **specific** class. In this case it is CSS selector for class `sale`.

Comment: Can you exemplify that?

Comment: @mx-Code, ngClass allow, e.g. `[ngClass]="{'myclass1':condition, 'mayclass2':condition2}"` or `[ngClass]="condition?'class1':'class2'` or `[ngClass]="variable_with_classname"`, `[class.sale]="variable"`only allow if variable (or condition) add the class and if not variable not add the class.

Answer (score 1):

To expand off Michael D's answer, it's a case of singular vs multiple classes.

Use of the `class` binding allows you to add or remove a single class at a time as you've shown in your question:

```
[class.sale]="onSale"
[class.error]="errors.length > 1"
```

`ngClass` on the other hand allows you to add or remove multiple classes through a single call like so:

```
[ngclass]="{'sale': onSale, 'error': errors.length > 1}"
```

With the style class appearing on the left and your expression for it on the right.

**EDIT**

I thought it might also be worth noting that you can also pass the classes as an object that you've defined in your component. For example, you may have the following in your component:

```
classes = {
    'sale': onSale,
    'error': errors.length > 1
}
```

You can then pass to the `[ngclass]` binding like so:

```
[ngClass]="classes"
```

Comment: See all this is possible with class also right? You can pass object with multiple entries, strings with different styles, array etc..

Comment: AFAIK, no. The class binding only allows you to manipulate a single class at a time. I generally find `ngClass` to be the better choice regardless as you don't have to change your syntax should you need to start toggling multiple different styles on a given element.

Comment: Here inside the docs: https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding. see the section class binding where you can pass an object ```{foo: true, bar: false}``` Aint it possible to bind multiple classes here. Or as a string ```'class1 class2 class3' && true || def-class```

Comment: If you're using `[class]` without a suffixed class name, by the looks of it you can use it the same way. I can't say I've seen that usage though. It could be a new implementation.

Comment: Something like this also possible ```{{class1 ? cond1 : class2}} {{class3 ? cond2 : class4}} ...```

Answer (score 1):

From Angular official documentation, you can read about :

syntax `[class]` in order to bind class using [Attribute, class, and style bindings](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-binding)

syntax `[ngClass]` in order to [add css to you html elements](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

regarding the effect of
`[class.className]='booleanVariable'`

it is the same as `[ngClass]="booleanVariable ? 'className' : ''"`

In both cases you can apply css on conditions.

Comment: A small correction. It would be `[ngClass]="booleanVariable ? 'className' : ''"`.